# App freezes when highlighting large pdf document using apple PDFKit

Tags: ios, swift, ios-pdfkit

Using the below code to highlight search text string in a pdf.

```
let selections = pdfView?.document?.findString(searchTerms!, withOptions: [.caseInsensitive])
        
        selections?.forEach { selection in
            selection.pages.forEach { page in
                let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
                highlight.endLineStyle = .square
                highlight.color = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9843137255, green: 0.9019607843, blue: 0.5529411765, alpha: 1)
                
                page.addAnnotation(highlight)
            }
        }
```

It works perfectly for small pdfs. But when there are about 2000 or above pages, app freezes. **selections** take some time. Is there a way to fix this. Tried with delegate for beginDocumentFind also. Same result

Comment: Have you tested wether the finding or the annotating is the issue?

Comment: findString will take so long...it depends on page number...if number of pages are more...delay will also be more